how to batch export blender files and unpack rescources in current file?
I have this script which batch export blend files. I also want it to unpack rescources in current file for each blender file.
But it unpacks all rescources from all blend files to the same folder "textures". I want it to unpack it for each blend file in an indiviual folder. Blender always creates a folder named "textures" to unpack the files but if I want to do it multiple times for multiple blend files, the folders need to have a unique name and cannot be named all "textures".
How can I do that?
import os


# folder containing blend files
ip_path = "C:\\"
ip_fname = "C:\\"

# target folder
op_path = "C:\\"

blendfiles = [ip_fname,]

def clear_cur_colls():
    while len(bpy.data.collections) > 0:
        bpy.data.collections.remove(bpy.data.collections[0])
    override = bpy.context.copy()
    override["area.type"] = ['OUTLINER']
    override["display_mode"] = ['ORPHAN_DATA']
    bpy.ops.outliner.orphans_purge()
    


def get_coll_names(assets_path):
    names = []
    with bpy.data.libraries.load(assets_path) as (data_from, data_to):
        names = [name for name in data_from.collections]
    return names

for file in blendfiles:
    # prep to make a folder based on blend file name
    filepath = os.path.join(ip_path, file)

    # make a folder based on blend file name to store new files
    if not os.path.isdir(op_path):
        os.mkdir(op_path)
    # get each object from blend file
    colls = get_coll_names(filepath)
    for coll in colls:
        # clear the current file
        clear_cur_colls()
        # append the object
        bpy.ops.wm.append(filepath=file, directory=str(filepath)+"\\Collection\\", filename=coll)
        
        bpy.ops.outliner.orphans_purge(do_recursive=True)
        # save blend file
        bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile(filepath=os.path.join(op_path, coll+".blend"))
        bpy.ops.file.unpack_all()
        bpy.ops.file.unpack_all(method='USE_LOCAL')
        

clear_cur_colls()
```


Why not just include part of your script to rename the auto-generated unpack folder into something else. That or you could just move all the files into a separate folder leaving that folder empty for the next one? Using the operator is a bit high level and doesn't seem like it allows for control like what you need. Might need to do it "manually".
